# Confusion with node locations in SpriteKit on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I'm still very new to Swift, Spritekit & iOS. I've been doing some experimenting and cant manage to work out why my objects are moving when I change scenes.

Here is a gfycat of what is happening.
https://gfycat.com/FlatAdeptFrenchbulldog

Im using the white box in either scene to switch back to the other. The white box is positioned in the same location in each scene, but after the first switch everything shifts.

My basic scene change code:

```
    let transition = SKTransition.fade(withDuration: 1)
    let nextScene = MenuScene(size: self.size)
    nextScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
```

I must be missing something pretty basic. Any help would be appreciated :)

*Edit*: Ive done a little more experimenting and noticed that CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) in my default scene is the very middle of the screen, and this changes to the bottom left after the scene changes. Im guessing this explains what is happening, but Im not sure why it happens?

Comment: It appears my problem related to the scenes anchor point, which was set at 0.5,0.5 in the first scene, and then being changed somehow to 0,0 when the scene changed.

Comment: Scene's anchorPoint by default is 0,0 (CGPointZero). So, for that particular scene, the anchorPoint is not changed to 0,0, but rather it's never set to 0.5,0.5... You can read here more : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html

Comment: @Whirlwind the default scene's `anchorPoint` is (0.5, 0.5) in Xcode 8. Also, `CGPointZero` is now `CGPoint.zero`.

Comment: @0x141E Ah, thanks. Haven't tried 8 yet.